# Materialize Slider in React class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a slider currently working in a react function component. I wonder how can I implement the below slider correctly in a React class component?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Slider from '@mui/material/Slider';

function valuetext(value) {
  return `${value}°C`;
}

export default function RangeSlider() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([20, 37]);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 300 }}>
      <br /><br />
      <Slider
        getAriaLabel={() => 'Temperature range'}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is not related to materialize

Comment: Let me know if you try the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focused on class components, you will have to:

- use `this.state` instead of `React.useState`
- You will need to use the constructor (and bind the `handleChange` function)
- That's All

You have a code sandbox working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-wildflower-kzjck?file=/src/ClassSlider.js

It'd be like:

```js
function valuetext(value) {
  return `${value}°C`;
}

class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: [20, 37] };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event, newValue) {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Box sx={{ width: 300 }}>
        <br />
        <br />
        <Slider
          getAriaLabel={() => "Temperature range"}
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          valueLabelDisplay="on"
          getAriaValueText={valuetext}
        />
      </Box>
    );
  }
}

export default ClassComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const minDistance = 10;

export default function MinimumDistanceSlider() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([20, 37]);

  const handleChange1 = (event, newValue, activeThumb) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(newValue)) {
      return;
    }

    if (activeThumb === 0) {
      setValue([Math.min(newValue[0], value[1] - minDistance), value[1]]);
    } else {
      setValue([value1[0], Math.max(newValue[1], value[0] + minDistance)]);
    }
  };
```

try this